# Do unit test programs in C# based on unit test library provided by Visual Studio need entry point?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I saw that for some code with some methods, its unit tests based on the unit test library provided by Visual Studio don't have entry point like `main` method in them.

So are the test programs compiled into executables?

Where are their entry points?

Thanks.

Comment: The tests themselves aren't an application host, the test runner application is.  It would use the compiled test libraries to execute tests.

Answer (score 3):

They're compiled as libraries (dlls). They do not have an entry point.

A test runner will load the library, inspect the public methods (and optionally filter based on attributes, depending on the runner), and then invoke each method.

Answer (score 2):

The Test Runner, in most cases Visual Studio, inspect assemblies to find classes marked with [TestClass] and methods marked with [TestMethod] attribute. Effectively what would go in a "Main" method is handled transparently to the developer.